# Animating time series and time-dependent symbology

Tags: qgis, time-series, animation, temporal-controller

I am looking to create an animation in QGIS of GPS collar data, showing movement over time. I would like to make each point fade away as the animation progresses, but am having an issue with the variable @map_start_time which is showing as a null value in the expression dialogue. The expression I would like to use is `day(@map_start_time - 'date')`

This variable works correctly in the map title decoration and accurately aligns between the temporal controller panel and the data on the map, so it is not a case of incorrect formatting. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]